# R shiny dynamic data function - how to change which CSV is accessed depending on date range input?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a dashboard that allows you to select certain dates, and depending on those dates have the corresponding CSV file accessed to change my output plot. In order to do this, do my CSVs need to be on a public site and use the getSymbols function? I already have the correct input and output structure, I'm just trying to figure out dynamic data set access. Any advice is helpful!

Comment: Dear Erin, welcome to SO! Could you post some data and code to illustrate your question, as well as expected output. At current state it's quite difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put your data on public site. [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) allows to store your data in your application folder. Please see the code which automatically loads csv-file depends on data input:

```
# csv file simulation
set.seed(123)
write.csv(data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)), "old.csv")
write.csv(data.frame(x = 100 * rnorm(100), y = 100 * rnorm(100)), "new.csv")



library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Dynamic loading of csv file"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("rb", "Choose one:",
                     choiceNames = list(
                       "old", "new"),
                     choiceValues = list(
                       2, 1
                     ))
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
     if(input$rb == 1) {
       df <- read.csv("new.csv", header = TRUE)
       clr <- "red"
     } else {
       df <- read.csv("old.csv", header = TRUE)
       clr <- "blue"
     }

      plot(df$x, df$y, col = clr)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```